# ifconfig cannot update my wireless connection settings

Tags: networking, network-manager

I set up a manual IPv4 connection and filled in the static IP, Mask, Gateway and DNS.
Now I want to edit them via command line. Name of my Ehernet device is ens160. I did this:

```
sudo ifconfig ens160 [MY New IP] netmask [My New netmask]
```

Now when I type ifconfig the respective details for my device have changed. But when I go to

> Edit Connections>>Select Wired Connection>>Edit>>IPv4 Settings

The details are still the same(unchanged) and due to these different settings I cannot access the Internet anymore.

What I basically want to do is change the IPv4 settings from the command line, such that the connection details are changed in the edit connection menu as well.

**EDIT :** Does the fact that my `/etc/network/interfaces` doesn't have a entry for ens160 device change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Those settings are applied to the hardware of the Ethernet adapted only as it transitions from DOWN to UP.

```
sudo ifconfig ens160 down
sudo ifconfig ens160 up
```

will apply your settings,

Comment: I have already tried that, when I do `sudo ifconfig ens160 up` my ifconfig data gets reverted back to the old IP instead of updating the hardware IP.

Comment: Please see my edit.